# Is the output signal of a smartphone's headphone jack AC?

Tags: amplifier

I am about to use my smartphone in an audio amplifier circuit as input.

I was wondering if the output from the smart phone's headphone jack is an AC signal so that I can use it in amplification.

Comment: Do you have a specification for the output stage on the particular smartphone you are talking about that you could link to? Ditto the amplifier you want to connect it to. Alternatively, you could supply circuit diagrams for both.

Comment: Of course it is. What else could it be?

Comment: Try to play a signal with non-zero DC component and see if you get non-zero DC component out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the ones having 3.5mm TRRS (tip-ring-ring-sleeve) output jack then yes, it's AC. It cannot be anything else as it's ready to be used by headphones. Some newer ones having no TRRS jack e.g. iPhones might be carrying audio digitally though, but we are not talking about these.

I used to use my smartphone when testing guitar amplifiers in musical stores before buying. It was quite useful back in the day as I never had to take my guitar to the store i.e. I was simulating my guitar with my smartphone by playing the dry signal of my guitar *(recorded with external sound devices and EQ-ed for smartphone playback)* and transferring the output to the amp with a 3.5mm-to-6.3mm converter. Memories...

To give an idea about signal levels: 32-ohm-headphones produce enough audio while being driven with a few to a few tens of milliwatts.